# MySQL connection appears to fail and breaks script

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application that uses two PHP scripts, one of which contains a form, and another which takes the values submitted in said form, and updates tables in a MySQL database based on said values. Both scripts connect to a MySQL database, but only the one with the form does so successfully. The submission succeeds, but when the script tries to connect to the database, it fails and the script crashes(ie, a blank screen is displayed). All the proper credentials are provided, and, so far as I know, correct syntax is used :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

mysql_connect("host", "uname", "pass") or die ($mysql_error);
mysql_select_db("phonelist") or die ($mysql_error);

$ext = $_POST['ext']
list($lname, $fname) = explode(' ',$_POST['input']);

$strQuery = "UPDATE phonelist SET number = " . $input . " WHERE last_name = " . $lname . "AND first_name = " $fname);
mysql_query($strQuery) or die("Query failed.");
```

Like I said, the same connection is created with success in the script that contains the submission form (used to populate a drop down list), so I'm not really sure why this is happening.

EDIT: Added more complete code from the second script. The first script is quite long so I'll try to show you the most relevant parts.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the content of both scripts. You might be making a tiny mistake that could cause this to break as well.

Comment: The code you show above should show "Connection failed." Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Please post the output of `mysql_error()`.

Comment: also try adding error_reporting(E_ALL); at your process code.

Comment: Error reporting is on, but I still don't get any output.

Comment: Is `display_errors` on as well? (You can ask `phpinfo()` if in doubt)

Comment: I see a syntax error in your code (a missing semicolon in line 6). Is it in the real code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to different database tables? Perhaps there is an issue with the format of your writable table. Be sure to verify the table and columns being used. Also, depending on whether you're using PreparedStatements, the parameters may be off. Perhaps you could post more details of your non-functioning script...

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment rather an answer?

Comment: They both connect to the same tables.